# Splitter value as interval for retrieving label?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums, modulo

I'm learning C# and Unity3D for a few months and now I stumbled on a logic, which hopefully somebody can describe to me.
(I already googled for hours and even looked up if other languages use enums that way.)

This code is from a free asset from the unity asset store, which I try to anatomize.

Everything is fine and understandable for me, but then it comes to the functions GetSliderData() and SetSliderData().

My Question: How does the modulo part works?

Why dividing anyway, when it comes to getting and setting values? Or is it some kind of syntax, like the lambda expression "=>" which is not ">="(less or equal sign)

Thank you in advance for your time!
Dom

```
public class SliderData : ScriptableObject
{
    // Data storage
    public List<float> sliderData;

    /* Use a single enum as retrieval label for any slider by using a splitter
     * value as interval. */
    private const int ENUM_INTERVAL = 16;
    public enum SliderField
    {
        // Customizer sliders
        DEPTH_MIN,
        DEPTH_MAX,
        PERLIN_SPEED,
        PERLIN_LEVEL,
        ZONE_PERLIN_SPEED,
        ZONE_PERLIN_LEVEL,
        MAP_PERLIN_SPEED,
        MAP_PERLIN_LEVEL,
    }

    /// Retrieves the value of the slider belonging to the given field constant.
    public float GetSliderData(SliderField field)
    {
        return sliderData[(int)field % ENUM_INTERVAL];
    }

    /// Sets the value of the slider belonging to the given field constant.
    public void SetSliderData(SliderField field, float value)
    {
        sliderData[(int)field % ENUM_INTERVAL] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is to get the remainder after the division... the value will alwayd be within 0 and the number you are dividing with

Answer (score 1):

The `%` seems to have the purpose of wrap-around the given `field` value onto the existing indices of the `sliderData` list.

If the value reaches/exceeds the `ENUM_INTERVAL` it will instead start over from `0`.

For your methods indeed this seems a bit redundant if using the enum values since there are only `8` of them anyway. But it could be triggered via type casting e.g. `(SliderField)17` .. but why would someone do that?

Anyway this seems to simply assume that the `sliderData` list contains at least `16` elements ...

---

In general to be honest I wouldn't use such a structure but rather store and access the values via actual fields instead of this kind of "dictionary" List.

Ofcourse depends on the use-case and how exactly your asset is used later. It seems there is some behavior involved you didn't share here.

But instead of going through the magic enum and list indices - why not simply have

```
public class SliderData : ScriptableObject
{
    public float DEPTH_MIN;
    public float DEPTH_MAX;
    public float PERLIN_SPEED;
    public float PERLIN_LEVEL;
    public float ZONE_PERLIN_SPEED;
    public float ZONE_PERLIN_LEVEL;
    public float MAP_PERLIN_SPEED;
    public float MAP_PERLIN_LEVEL;
}
```

Comment: The only reason I could see the model in the question being useful is if there was some additional custom handler for getting or setting the properties, such as a PropertyChanged event, that they wanted to avoid writing repetitious code for - that said, that is clearly not the case there.

Comment: wow! many thanks for both answers! that cleared it up for me! 
I'm also not a big fan of enums, since I've first heard of scriptable objects in a unite2016 video. Just like in your code example!

And yes, it is part of a custom handler, you were right, Zaelin!

thanks! :)